# calculate incremental inverse square values from $0$ to a value

Tags: square-numbers

I would like to calculate $20$ inverse square values from $897–3773$, but am unsure how to really even begin.

I am attempting to set the voltage on a servo motor that moves a magnet away from a metal source, such that I have a constant difference between each setting ($20$ of them), and am fairly certain this means I need to move the magnet smaller increments at first, then grow larger.

For example I know the following values:

```
 x, y
-------
 1, 3773
 2, 3662
 5, 3336
10, 2677
15, 2064
19, 1293
20, 897
```

These are voltage reads, so not *exact*, but even plotting by hand it's clear it's not linear.

Any advice would be much appreciated.  If anything, how to better think about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly you want to interpolate $19$ values (so $20$ steps) between $x=897$ and $x=3773$ on the $x$ axis so that the function $y=1/x^2$ has constant increments.

To do that, divide the interval between $1/897^2$ and $1/3773^2$ into equal intervals. For each division point $p$ the value of $x$ will be $1/\sqrt{p}$.

Comment: That is _precisely_ what I was hoping to achieve.  Thanks so much!